Different page margins for text and display math
I would like to setup the document so that the colum of text has a fairly narrow width on the page but equations still have room to expand on both sides.
Basically I'd like to make it so that text sits in the page as-if page margins were like 2in (left & right), whereas equations should behave as-if the page margins were 0.5in.
I tried to mock it up in the image below (but, ideally, the equation content would be wider).
Is it possible?


yes, if you insert each display equation in wider environment, for example by use of the ``changepage` package.

Surely this is only for the odd case where you have an equation has to have some extra room, right? This can be easily handled manually in those instances.

@Werner since most equations are larger than the text I'd rather have them all of the same width and not go for a case by case basis.

the second part of @cabohah's answer here solves my problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721699/124018
